# Is it okay to ask question having intention to have historical significance?

Tags: discussion

There are a lot of question in the site which has "historical significance" like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read). My question is, is it okay to ask this type of question intentionally?

- If no, why not? one would get much more reputation comparing to the other questions in the site, why should one miss the chance?
- If yes, why yes? it is written that, *"please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here"*.

Comment: How did you miss `but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site`?

Comment: No, it isn't, because the reason they're locked as having historical significance is that **they're no longer considered on-topic**. The only way a new question could subsequently  have *"historical significance"* is if it was **currently** on topic, then became upvoted/well-answered/etc., then the rules changed such that it was no longer on topic. If you ask a question that's *currently off-topic*, then it's just off-topic and gets closed/downvoted/etc.

Comment: "*please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here*" The questions were previously on-topic, but are now off-topic. It is not ever good to knowingly post an off-topic question.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, I did not miss that, but keeping them with showing high votes does not encourage to have such type of question?

Comment: Well that's why they have a clear warning to the contrary, with **bold text** and everything. And note that your argument *"one would get much more reputation"* doesn't hold up, because if you try asking such a question now it will get a rather less positive reaction.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, that means those questions were on-topic at that time?

Comment: @manetsus that's correct; when posted, they *were* on-topic.

Answer (score 8):

It's totally ok to ask questions that you hope will be historically significant. For instance, asking how to accomplish something critical in a new release of a major API where the documentation is missing or unclear can not only help *you*, but motivate the creation of something that will have lasting value to hundreds if not thousands of other people!

But, **it is NOT ok to ask bad questions that you hope people will like enough that they'll keep them around anyway.**

Ask for solutions to real problems that you face when programming. If you want to chew the fat, [hop into chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 6):

No. Questions to be asked are expected to follow the site scope as described by the **[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and the **[help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)**.

The **[historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/historical-lock/info)** is applied to **preserve valuable information** that is **no longer considered acceptable to ask on the site**. This means that new contributions should not attempt to reconstruct them.

> Questions can be historically locked when:
>
> 1. The post is Off-Topic or Not Constructive, and
> 2. The post is stellar, in spite of its off-topic nature, and
> 3. There are a large number of views, upvotes and inbound links on the post, and
> 4. The post is contentious; i.e. it has been closed and reopened at least once, or deleted and undeleted at least once